# How to query for queues that have a specific word in it

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

What I was doing is:

```
rabbitmq_queue_messages_published{queue="Specific.Queue.String.With.TheWord.Apple"}
```

to get the number of messages published in the `Specific.Queue.String.With.TheWord.Apple` queue.

But I have like... 50 queues that I want to look at, whose commonality is that they have this word in the queue name.

How do I query for the number of messages published in queues with this specific word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [regex label filter](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors):

```
rabbitmq_queue_messages_published{queue=~".*TheWord.*"}
```

Note that `.*` must be added at both sides of `TheWord`, since Prometheus automatically adds [anchors](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html) to the regexp. I.e. it converts `regexp` to `^(?:regexp)$`